# Cannot install llvm-9 or clang-9 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: llvm, ubuntu-16.04, llvm-clang, apt

I have not been able to install either llvm version 9 or clang version 9 on Ubuntu. We have installed them on Windows.

I have tried a command and saw this response.

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...
Done E: Unable to locate package llvm-9
```

I have also tried and saw this response.

```
sudo apt-get install clang-9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package clang-9
```

My **/etc/apt/sources.list** file contains

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-9.0 main
```

I found the website and saw that the folder was **llvm-toolchain-xenial-9**. Trying that version did not work either.

What else can I do?

I have looked at downloading the binaries but am not sure what installation steps I might be missing. I am not interested in compiling source code.

Answer (score 5):

The Clang/LLVM project provides Nightly build packages for Ubuntu and Debian.

See the https://apt.llvm.org

> The goal is *to provide Debian and Ubuntu [Clang and LLVM] packages ready to be installed with minimal impact on the distribution*.
>   Packages are available for amd64 and i386 (except for recent Ubuntu) and for both the stable, old-stable and development branches (currently 8, 9 and 10).
>
> *Packages are built using stage2 and extremely similar to the one shipping in Debian & Ubuntu.*

To use:

- Add the appropriate repositories to the /etc/apt/sources.list file; there are distinct repos for different Debian and Ubuntu versions.
- Add the apt key (shown in the link).
- **Run an `apt update`** to refresh the cache.
- Add packages with `apt install clang-9` (or other package as desired).

---

**If something "did not work" using the vetted package system, diagnose that issue directly**. Xenial has Clang/LLVM 9 packages, and I've recently installed the packages into Disco.

The described symptom ("Unable to locate package") sounds as though one ***neglected to run `apt update`***, in which case the packages from the newly-added sources would not be visible to apt. This is a tool-usage issue, not a lack of available packages.

Comment: `apt install` generated the message "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 295 not upgraded." `llvm-cov` is version 9.0.0 dated Sept 19.

Comment: @J-A-Brown `apt install clang-9`? That will either successfully install clang-9, report it's already installed (yay!), or report a useful error. The LLVM page recommends a number of core packages; adapt to needs. The error message in the post ("Unable to locate package clang-9") is due to mis-configured sources or non-updated cache.

Comment: I was able to generate code coverage using the gcc compiler. I was satisfied with that solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
                            LLVM INSTALLATION STEPS
                            -----------------------
```

---

### LLVM Compiler Prerequisites:

```
    OPERATING SYSTEM    :   Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

    RAM                 :   Minimum 16GB to 32GB

    SWAP MEMORY         :   Minimum 10GB to 20GB

    MEMORY  NEEDED      :   Minimum 70GB
```

## Install CMake version 3.5.1:

```
    $sudo apt install cmake
```

---

### LLVM Compiler Installation Steps

Step1:
    #download llvm from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-8.0.1/llvm-8.0.1.src.tar.xz

```
#download clang from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-8.0.1/cfe-8.0.1.src.tar.xz

#extract files into folders:
            tar -xf cfe-8.0.1.src.tar.xz
            tar -xf llvm-8.0.1.src.tar.xz

#change directory names to llvm8 and clang

            mv cfe-8.0.1.src clang
```

### mv llvm-8.0.1.src llvm8

Step2 : #change present working directory to llvm_source_directory here it is llvm8

```
$cd llvm8

##create build directory

$mkdir build

##change pwd to build directory

$cd build

#Build (PATH =/llvm8/build) 

#execute following command in build directory:
```

### $cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Unix Makefiles" ../

Step3:  #execute make command in pwd:

### /llvm8/build$ make

Step4 : #after 100% of linking process execute following command in build directory:

```
$sudo make install
```

### $ sudo reboot

step5 : #after installation restart your system!

```
#for checking llvm installation type

$llvm-config --version      #it shows 8.0.1

$clang --version            #it shows 8.0.1
```

Comment: I downloaded `clang+llvm-9.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04.tar.xz` and extracted it. Even in its `bin` folder running `clang --version` shows 3.8.0. Running `./clang --version` shows 9.0.0. What got missed?

Comment: @J-A-Brown `./clang` is executable in current directory, without `./` another executable from `PATH`

Comment: I did this for clang-10. I am getting this error: /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lLLVMExtensions

Answer (score 2):

Here are the commands for LLVM 9:

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang-9 libclang-9-dev llvm-9-dev
```